# Bateman-Horn over finite fields

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

So the Bateman Horn conjecture asserts for any irreducible $f_1(x), f_2(x), \ldots, f_k(x)\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$, where $f_1(x)f_2(x)\cdots f_k(x)$ has no fixed divisor, there exist infinitely many $n\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $f_1(n), f_2(n), \ldots, f_k(n)$ are all simultaneously primes in $\Bbb{Z}$, and in fact predicts a specific asymptotic distribution for them.

Now I read somewhere that an analogous conjecture is false, replacing $\Bbb{Z}$ with $\Bbb{F_q}[t]$ for any finite field $\Bbb{F_q}$.

Could someone explain why this is true?  I've seen a counterexample polynomial before, but I wasn't able to convince myself of its necessary compositeness.  Perhaps I just missed something simple

Comment: Something other than what is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That example is fine, but I don't understand its necessary compositeness